# Linq: ForEach item return the number of items needed to get n unique items starting at that item

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have a list of items:

```
[a,b,b,a,c,d,a,d,b,c]
```

and I need to know, for each item, how many items along do I have to traverse till I get n unique items, (and return eg -1, or otherwise indicate if that's not possible)

So here, if n = 4, I would return

```
[6,5,4,6,5,5,4,-1,-1,-1]
```

since

a,b,b,a,c,d contains 4 unique elements

b,b,a,c,d contains 4 unique elements

b,a,c,d contains 4 unique elements,

a,c,d,a,d,b contains 4 unique elements

etc.

Comment: This question, as is, is too broad since it does not show any kind of attempt from your side, regardless of the self-answer.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense as well.  Why do you display an array of numbers when you have an array of letters?  If you wanted 4 unique items why do have -1 in your array 3 times instead of just once?

Comment: Does a lack of attempt make it too broad?

Comment: @johnny5, for each letter, return the number of items along the list I need to traverse to get n unique items

Comment: Okay thanks, that makes sense now

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y Problem, what are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Don't ask questions as you understand it, write as we don't understand it.

Comment: @johnny5 Each item has a page number, and my final output is the smallest range of pages containing n unique items.

Comment: @mshwf, which perticular bit don't you understand, and I'll try and make that clearer. Usually I try and make my questions as clear as possible, but this is a tricky concept to explain.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @mshwf
I have used stack overflow before, I have written many Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples, and if instead of being snarky, you could actually be helpful, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I sometimes go to this page to learn how to write question, no offense here.
write actual code, your answer below seems to be a try, include it in the question and ask for a more-performant code, although in this case [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be a suitable forum for this problem. you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
List.Select((x,i) => {
    var range = List.Skip(i).GroupBy(y => y).Take(n);
    if (range.Count() == n)
        return range.SelectMany(y => y).Count();
    return -1;
});
```

Although i'm pretty sure this is horribly non-performant.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question or is the question how can you make this code better?

Comment: It's both. It is a valid answer, but I would appreciate a better one

Answer (score 0):

To try to minimize overhead, I created a `ListSpan` extension class for managing subparts of a `List` - something like `ArraySegment` for `List`, but (loosely) modeled on `Span`:

```
public class ListSpan<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable {
    List<T> baseList;
    int start;
    int len;

    public ListSpan(List<T> src, int start = 0, int? len = null) {
        baseList = src;
        this.start = start;
        this.len = len ?? (baseList.Count - start);
        if (this.start + this.len > baseList.Count)
            throw new ArgumentException("start+len > Count for ListSpan");
    }

    public T this[int n]
    {
        get
        {
            return baseList[start + n];
        }
        set
        {
            baseList[start + n] = value;
        }
    }

    public class ListSpanEnumerator<Te> : IEnumerator<Te>, IEnumerator {
        int pos;
        List<Te> baseList;
        int end;
        Te cur = default(Te);

        public ListSpanEnumerator(ListSpan<Te> src) {
            pos = src.start - 1;
            baseList = src.baseList;
            end = src.start + src.len;
        }

        public Te Current => cur;
        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;
        public bool MoveNext() {
            if (++pos < end) {
                cur = baseList[pos];
                return true;
            }
            else {
                cur = default(Te);
                return false;
            }
        }
        public void Reset() => pos = 0;
        public void Dispose() { }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => new ListSpanEnumerator<T>(this);
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
public static class ListExt {
    public static ListSpan<T> Slice<T>(this List<T> src, int start = 0, int? len = null) => new ListSpan<T>(src, start, len);
}
```

Then I created an extension method to return the distance (in `Take` terms) required to get n unique items from an `IEnumerable`:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static int DistanceToUnique<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, int n, IEqualityComparer<T> cmp = null) {
        var hs = new HashSet<T>(cmp ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
        var pos = 0;
        using (var e = src.GetEnumerator()) {
            while (e.MoveNext()) {
                ++pos;
                hs.Add(e.Current);
                if (hs.Count == n)
                    return pos;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Now the answer is relatively straight forward:

```
var ans = Enumerable.Range(0, src.Count).Select(p => src.Slice(p).DistanceToUnique(n));
```

Basically I go through each position in the original (`src`) `List` and compute the distance to n unique values from that position using a `ListSpan` of the `List` starting at that position.

This still isn't terribly efficient in that I am creating a `HashSet` for every element in the original `List` and putting all the following elements in it, and traversing the elements up to k! times for a k element `List`. Still trying to come up with something really efficient.